# Show help of commands in SQLite shell?

Tags: sqlite

Any command to show the usage of a command or a SQL statement?

Such as (though none works here):

```
.help schema
.help .schema
.help INSERT
.help SELECT
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the overview shown by `.help`, the is no more information in the shell.

You have to use the on-line documentation of the [shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) or the [SQL language](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).